# Problem facing with "keras" is not a known member of module "tensorflow"PylancereportAttributeAccessIssue

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

Problem facing with tensorflow and keras in visual studio.

I have successfully pip installed tensorflow along with keras.

But somehow i am getting the following error.

ERROR:
"keras" is not a known member of module "tensorflow" Pylance (reportAttributeAccessIssue).

The below is my code and the error is mentioned below of the code.

CODE:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import os

# Initialize Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the trained model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("trained_model.h5")

# Define route for model prediction
@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    # Check if request contains file data
    if "file" not in request.files:
        return jsonify({"error": "No file provided"}), 400
    
    # Get the file from the request
    file = request.files["file"]
    
    # Save the file to a temporary location
    temp_image_path = "temp_image.jpg"
    file.save(temp_image_path)
    
    # Preprocess the image
    img = Image.open(temp_image_path)
    img = img.resize((180, 180))  # Resize image to match model input size
    img = np.array(img) / 255.0  # Normalize pixel values
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)  # Add batch dimension
    
    # Make prediction
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    
    # Remove temporary image file
    os.remove(temp_image_path)
    
    # Return prediction result
    return jsonify({"prediction": int(np.argmax(prediction))}), 200

# Run the Flask app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

ERROR:

"keras" is not a known member of module "tensorflow" Pylance (reportAttributeAccessIssue)

Comment: I am getting the above error at the following line.

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("trained_model.h5")

Comment: It's a false positive by Pylance. If your goal is just to suppress the warning, import keras explicitly: `import keras`